# Numpy aggregate into bins, then calculate sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
M = [[1, 200],
 [1.8, 100],
 [2, 500],
 [2.5, 300],
 [3, 400],
 [3.5, 200],
 [5, 200],
 [8, 100]]
```

I want to group the rows by a bin size (applied to the left column), e.g. for a bin size 2 (first bin is values from 0-2, second bin from 2-4, third bin from 4-6 etc):

```
[[1, 200],
 [1.8, 100],
----
 [2, 500],
 [2.5, 300],
 [3, 400],
 [3.5, 200],
----
 [5, 200],
----
 [8, 100]]
```

Then output a new matrix with the sum of the right columns for each group:

```
[200+100, 500+300+400+200, 200, 100]
```

What is an efficient way to sum each value based on the bin_size boundaries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### With `pandas`:

Make a `DataFrame` and then use integer division to define your bins:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(M)
df.groupby(df[0]//2)[1].sum()

#0
#0.0     300
#1.0    1400
#2.0     200
#4.0     100
#Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Use `.tolist()` to get your desired output:

```
df.groupby(df[0]//2)[1].sum().tolist()
#[300, 1400, 200, 100]
```

---

### With `numpy.bincount`

```
import numpy as np

gp, vals = np.transpose(M)
gp = (gp//2).astype(int)

np.bincount(gp, vals)
#array([ 300., 1400.,  200.,    0.,  100.])
```

Comment: Appreciate! Same methods apply for Numpy too? Would like to implement with Numpy

Comment: There are other ways to define bins in general if they can't be defined easily by integer division; we just got lucky here.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `np.digitize` and a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` here:

```
bins = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
b = np.digitize(M[:, 0], bins)
v = M[:, 1]
```

Now using a vectorized `groupby` using a `csr_matrix`

```
from scipy import sparse

sparse.csr_matrix(
    (v, b, np.arange(v.shape[0]+1)), (v.shape[0], b.max()+1)
).sum(0)
```

```
matrix([[ 300., 1400.,  200.,    0.,  100.]])
```